# Curl didn't work PHP, always return empty esponse

Tags: codeigniter, curl, php-curl

I always get the return empty when I call my api with this code, but it work on my Insomnia, and on my shell

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($this->body));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $return_data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        if ($return_data) return $return_data;
        else return "empty";
```

my curl_getinfo return :

```
[content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 500
[header_size] => 543
[request_size] => 164
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.269685
[namelookup_time] => 0.002741
[connect_time] => 0.024587
[pretransfer_time] => 0.157608
[size_upload] => 636
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 2364
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 636
[starttransfer_time] => 0.157693
[redirect_time] => 0
```

Comment: [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 500
    [header_size] => 543
    [request_size] => 164
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.269685
    [namelookup_time] => 0.002741
    [connect_time] => 0.024587
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.157608
    [size_upload] => 636
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 2364
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 636
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.157693
    [redirect_time] => 0
That's my curl_getinfo

Comment: Hello, maybe you can add a line before closing the curl  "$err = curl_error($curl);" and echo it, well in this case you can actually see what's the error behind it.

Comment: I get empty result too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem, thanks to insomnia who can generate PHP code for cURL,

 I put the answer in case someone need it

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Accept-Charset: UTF-8",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ],
    ]);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
```